# Find best case scenario C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following to solve and I'm not sure how to approach this:

There are parking lots that are adjacent to each other and their placement resembles a straight line. Each parking lot has a value (profit) assigned to it. You can purchase as many lots as you want BUT they have to be adjacent to each other (in a contiguous set).

INPUT (THIS IS GIVEN/WHAT YOU WOULD TYPE IN):

Number of lots: 9

Value for each parking lot: ie: -5, 0, 7, -6, 4, 3, -5, 0, 2

Representation (for easier viewing)
Each box contains profit of a each lot:

[image]

OUTPUT:
Should be:
3 6 8
meaning: 
3 - start lot #,
6 - ending lot #,
8 - total profit (7 - 6 + 4 + 3)

If there is more than one answer, program should write the one that contains the smallest number of parking lots. If there is still more than one possible answer, your program can write any of them.

Please help. thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I got it working:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The problem 2.
    /// </summary>
    public class MySuperAwesomeClass
    {
        #region Constants and Fields

        /// <summary>
        /// The seq end.
        /// </summary>
        private static int seqEnd = -1;

        /// <summary>
        /// The seq start.
        /// </summary>
        private static int seqStart;

        #endregion

        // Quadratic maximum contiguous subsequence sum algorithm.
        #region Public Methods and Operators

        /// <summary>
        /// The max sub sum 2.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="a">
        /// The a.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The max sub sum 2.
        /// </returns>
        public static int maxSumSub(int[] a)
        {
            int maxSum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                int thisSum = 0;
                for (int j = i; j < a.Length; j++)
                {
                    thisSum += a[j];

                    if (thisSum > maxSum)
                    {
                        maxSum = thisSum;
                        seqStart = i;
                        seqEnd = j;
                    }
                }
            }

            return maxSum;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// The main.
        /// </summary>
        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter N:");
            string stringInput = Console.ReadLine();
            int[] a = new int[Convert.ToInt16(stringInput)];

            Console.WriteLine("Enter profit values:");
            for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt16(stringInput); i++)
            {
                string value = Console.ReadLine();
                a[i] = Convert.ToInt16(value);
            }

            int maxSum = maxSumSub(a);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", seqStart, seqEnd, maxSum));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Except I can't figure out this part:
If there is more than one answer, program should write the one that contains the smallest number of parking lots.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I'm thinking I should find the largest digit in the set first...

Comment: You haven't said what you're trying to do. How do you find an answer? Are you trying to find the greatest sum of contiguous subset of numbers?

Comment: yes. For the sample input above, you have an output listed.

Comment: You question is to find minimum number of adjacent lots having maximum profit. Am i correct?

Comment: I dont fully understand the question. Where do the numbers(/profit) to populate the array come from?

Comment: You type them in. Type in number of lots (in my example 9), then type in value/profit for each lot.

Comment: Check for a tie on sum and smaller number of values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the classic **Maximum subset sum problem**. No code as this is homework, but here is the general solution. I'm sure you can find code online by searching the title if you still get stuck.

1. Make first/last index variables for the max subset. These will hold the parking spaces of our answer. 3 and 6 respectively in your example.
2. Make a sum variable for the sum of the max subset. This will hold the sum of our answer. 8 in your example.
3. Make another set of first/last/sum variables which we will be our "current" variables.
4. Start at the beginning of the parking spaces. Place the current first and current last variable at the start and update the sum.
5. Now you're going to loop through each parking space by moving the current last variable and updating the sum.
6. If the current sum is greater then the max-so-far sum, save all the current variables into the max-so-far variables.
7. If at any point our current sum dips into the negative or becomes zero, our subset is not helping us get a max anymore, so restart it by moving the current first to where current last is and resetting current sum to zero.
8. Once we get to the end return the max-so-far variables

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint for a way you can make the algorithm more efficient: look at how the totals from each end add up.  For example, from what you provided, from the left side the totals would be -5, -5, 2, -4, 0, 3, -2, -2, 0, and from the right side they would be 2, 2, -3, 0, 4, -2, 5, 5, 0.